# Save and Open image in a temporary folder

Tags: python, vtk

I've made this function to convert a DICOM image to a png setting the values of window/level:

```
from vtk import vtkDICOMImageReader
from vtk import vtkImageMapToWindowLevelColors
from vtk import vtkPNGWriter

def dcm2png(inp, out, window, level):
    reader = vtkDICOMImageReader()
    reader.SetFileName(inp)
    reader.Update()

    windowlevel = vtkImageMapToWindowLevelColors()
    windowlevel.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())

    windowlevel.SetWindow(window)
    windowlevel.SetLevel(level)
    windowlevel.Update()

    writer = vtkPNGWriter()
    writer.SetFileName(out)
    writer.SetInputConnection(windowlevel.GetOutputPort())
    writer.Write()
```

But using this function I need to save the output file to a directory, however I wanna save the output file to a temporary file, but using this as an argument of function or other way similar because I use this function in my program, and after save it, I wanna open it outside the function, how could I do this?

I know [temfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) can do that, but I don't know how.

Comment: vtkPNGWriter could save anywhere, including temporary file ... did you tried and didn't worked ?